# c# - default try catch behavior strange?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I have some code such as this..

```
try
{
      ...
      this.vsg.LOOffset = 0;
      ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
      this.logger.Error(e, "Error setting up band edge measurement");
      throw new Exception("Error setting up band edge measurement", e);
}
```

I know the code breaks in an inner function when I set `this.vsg.LOOffset=0.` However, when it does this, it does not go into the catch function. It backs out and goes to a try catch I have further up in the surface in the code.

I tried changing one thing...

```
try
{
      ...
      try
      {
          this.vsg.LOOffset = 0;
      }
      catch
      {
         var x = 2;
      }
      ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
      this.logger.Error(e, "Error setting up band edge measurement");
      throw new Exception("Error setting up band edge measurement", e);
}
```

Now my code actually goes into the inner catch function and continues through the rest of the code without problem. Why does this happen?

Comment: What exception does `this.vsg.LOOffset = 0;` produce?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine and this code contains several big mistakes. There are two articles on the topic I link often: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/vexing-exceptions | https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: That's not possible. Perhaps `this.Logger.Error` is throwing?

Comment: _"It backs out and goes to a try catch I have further up"_ - with what stacktrace and Message/ExceptionType?

Comment: ow my code actually goes into the inner catch function and continues through the rest of the code without problem < it's because you don't throw on inner try catch

Comment: To get this straight: You do _not_ see the log for line `this.logger.Error(e, "Error setting up band edge measurement");`, is that right? If you do, then that's expected behavior since you rethrow (the wrong way, btw).

Answer (score 0):

In this code ...

```
Console.WriteLine("1");
try
{
    SomethingThatThrows();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("2");
    throw new Exception(ex);
}
Console.WriteLine("3");
```

I would *not* expect to see "3" on the Console. I'd expect to see "1" and "2". And the ControlFlow jump to the caller (probably a catch-block there).

If this is what you observe *and not expect* then your expectation is wrong.

If you do not want this behavior, then remove the line `throw new Exception(ex);` (which corresponds to `throw new Exception("Error setting up band edge measurement", e);` in your example code).

If you **do** want to rethrow, I'd suggest to change this to a simple `throw;` - which is different:

> `throw;` preserves the original stack trace of the exception, which is stored in the Exception.StackTrace property. Opposite to that, `throw e;` updates the StackTrace property of e.

-  [Note on "The throw statement"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements#the-throw-statement)

And last but not least there is the possibility that your `this.logger.Error` call is throwing for some reason. But we cannot see that from the question info.

Maybe this little Demo makes it clearer: [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/67YL5T)